# Phpmyadmin on elementary os doesn't work

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin on elementary os luna, but it is not found on browser.
I have done these commands

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and this command too

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf'
```

but when i tried to access phpmyadmin, my browser downloaded a file like this

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * forms frameset
 *
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['cfg']['QueryHistoryDB']
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['user']
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabServer']     as src for the mainframe
 * @uses    $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabDatabase']   as src for the mainframe
and so on.....
```

i have installed apache2 and php5 before

what did probably i do wrong?

Comment: You probably don't have PHP (and the Apache PHP module) installed

Comment: i have installed apache2 and php5 before

Answer (score 0):

Download and install xampp for linux. Its effective. Most important: is that php is not enabled on your system. That's why you see the php code.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be a missing dependency issue with your php5 install - possibly libapache2-mod-php5. You could first try running this to resolve missing dependencies with all packages:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then restart apache and try to view the page again.

You should also double check to make sure apache is configured to load the php module. Go into the "httpd.conf" file in for apache and look for a line like this:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

Make sure that's in there and then again restart apache.

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php